# Pouring concrete for fence posts in heavy rain

Tags: concrete, rain

My contractor just poured the concrete and set the posts for a new fence we are getting and much of the work was done in the pouring rain. Will this hurt the concrete and effect how it holds up down the line?

Comment: I have poured in the rain very few times as it has to be covered. a fence post will probably be fine if it was a good mix.  Concrete will cure under water. the top at ground level may look a bit like exposed aggregate if it wasn’t covered but it is better than being two hot (causing cracks) or two cold and not setting up .

Comment: Good comment. Should've been an answer.

Comment: @EdBeal If you have an answer, please post it below. Comments do not have the features to properly vet content and, as far as system is concerned, this question remains 'unanswered' . Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

All concrete sets up under water.  http://www.cement.org/cement-concrete-basics/faqs

The only thing that will be impacted is the finish.  If the top was not covered then the concrete will take on a bumpy appearance as the finer material may wash away and expose the aggregate.

Comment: I don't know if it's fair to say "the only thing that will be impacted is the finish".  The more water added to the mix, the lower the strength.  Whether enough extra water was added to have an important effect in this case is questionable, but definitely there's an impact on the strength.

Comment: @JoelKeene, Adding water to the mix is very different from rainwater sitting on top of the concrete.

Answer (score 0):

ACI 301prohibits the placement of concrete in rain without "adequate protection".

Comment: This is more of a great comment than a mediocre answer.

Comment: @ojait It's the only objective answer possible at present without more information. ACI 301 is incorporated by reference into typical building codes, e.g. IBC. Fences are occupancy type U under IBC. Hence if there are building codes in force the installation is unlikely to be in compliance. The only other objective answers are wait X years and see if it holds up, or, hire an engineer to take concrete samples, analyze the loads and write a report. Or to go meta, maybe the question is a help me fight my contractor issue.

Comment: -I agree. Now post your comment above as the answer. Good answer.